# Sum integers in each row of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I want to sum the integer values per row of an indexed array of indexed arrays.

Sample data sets (individual `$dataHitung2` from my code below):

```
[[3136], [9]]
```

and

```
[[3025], [169]]
```

Desired result:

```
[3145, 3194]
```

This is my code:

```
function hitung(){
    $dataTest       = array(60,50);
    $dataHitung     = array();
    $dataHitung2    = array();
    $dataRuspini    = $this->m_knn->getRuspini();
    foreach ($dataRuspini as $key => $val) {
        # code...
        // looping kolom 1 sampai 3
        for ($i=0; $i < count($val)-1; $i++) { 
            # code...
            // looping setiap baris per kolomnya
            for ($j=0; $j < count($val[$i]); $j++) { 
                # code...
                // data test dikurangi data training
                $dataHitung[$i][$j] = $dataTest[$i] - $val[$i];
                // hasil pengurangan dikuadratkan
                $dataHitung[$i][$j] = pow($dataHitung[$i][$j], 2);
                $dataHitung2[$i][$j] = $dataHitung[$i][$j];
            }
        }
        //var_dump(array_sum($dataHitung2));
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($dataHitung2);  
    }
```

How can I sum each row of the array?

Comment: please put a valid php array

Comment: The advices below can be reduced to `var_export(array_map('array_sum', $array));`

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_sum()`. The `array_sum()` function returns the sum of all the values in the array.

```
foreach($dataRuspini as $key=>$array)
{
 $sum_array[] = array_sum($array);
} 
print_r($sum_aray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$b = array_map(function($item){
     return array_sum($item);
 }, $dataRuspini);
print_r($b);
```

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) - Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays

[array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) - Calculate the sum of values in an array